# Need help replacing this super old shower handle!

Tags: shower, replacement

Not really sure what kind of handle this is or how to replace it. It doesn't work anymore so no water comes out of the showerhead. There's some little pin in the base of the handle that broke and none of the hardware stores around here have any replacement parts for it. I'd really like to remove and replace it with something more modern.

[image]

Comment: I cant tell what brand that is, there are literally dozens and dozens (old, new, foreign, domestic). Your picture does provide a clue though: The hatched area around the external part of that *collar* is a hint that it must be unscrewed to remove the handle and valve guts. Once apart, take all pieces to a good plumbing shop, not a "big box" store.

Comment: Thank you for that, Jimmy! I only work with local hardware shops that are more personal than the big box stores.  Would I have to turn the water off to take the parts off? I'm really, really not savvy in this area.

Comment: YES! The water needs to be off before removing that cap.

Comment: It looks like some putty or glue has been applied to the back side of that collar.  For that and other reasons I would not be too optimistic about being able to open this, buy parts, and put it back together easily.  Advice from a DIYer: If this bathroom has its own shutoff valve, shut it off, and go at it.  If not, I never bite off projects that could leave the family without water for days.  Hire a plumber who has the experience and skill, once the job is started, to get it to a stable state with the water back on within a few hours, even if that means opening the wall and replacing it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find matching parts, you will need to open up the wall and get a new shower diverter. You might be able to do it without damaging the tile if you approach it from the other side of the wall. You can do the work with push fittings and it will be relatively simple that way.

Comment: If you are forced to open up your wall, many times you can do that from the backside (other side) of the wall to preserve the tile.    You’ll still end up with a drywall repair to do but without a tile project, too.